# Generating a character class

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to censor letters in a word with `word.gsub(/[^#{guesses}]/i, '-')`, where `word` and `guesses` are strings.

When `guesses` is `""`, I get this error `RegexpError: empty char-class: /[^]/i`. I could sort such cases with an if/else statement, but can I add something to the regex to make it work in one line?

Comment: Add some character that will never appear in the words, like `#` or `%`: `word.gsub(/[^%#{guesses}]/i, '-')`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only matching (or not matching) letters, you can add a non-letter character to your regex, e.g. `#` or `%`:

```
word.gsub(/[^%#{guesses}]/i, '-')
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Zdhl2n)

If `#{guesses}` is empty, the regex will still be valid, and since `%` does not appear in a word, there is no risk of censuring some guessed percentage sign.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. One is to avoid testing if your matches are empty, that is:

```
unless (guesses.empty?)
  word.gsub(/^#{Regex.escape(guesses)}/i, '-')
end
```

Although that's not your intention, it's really the safest plan here and is the most clear in terms of code.

Or you could use the [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) function instead, though only for non-empty strings, so this could be substituted inside the `unless` block:

```
word.tr('^' + guesses.downcase + guesses.upcase, '-')
```

Generally `tr` performs better than `gsub` if used frequently. It also doesn't require any special escaping.

**Edit**: Added a note about `tr` not working on empty strings.

Since `tr` treats `^` as a special case on empty strings, you can use an embedded ternary, but that ends up confusing what's going on considerably:

```
word.tr(guesses.empty? ? '' : ('^' + guesses.downcase + guesses.upcase), '-')
```

Comment: The second option seems to take `^` with the escaped meaning when `guesses` is empty.

Comment: Yes. `"foo^bar".tr("^", "") #=> "foobar"`.

Comment: My answer is that you should use `empty?` as a test in either case. I hope that's not too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This may look somewhat similar to tadman's answer.

Probably you should keep the string that represents what you want to hide, instead of what you want to show. Let's say this is `remains`. Then, it would be easy as:

```
word.tr(remains.upcase + remains.downcase, "-")
```